# Can not get the changed value of input fields which are created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button in my Html. If I clicked the button then two input field generates. I set a default value for the input fields. But I want to change the value. Whenever I change any value, I try to get the changed value of the input field through jQuery. But I can not access that. I only get the `event.target`. But I want the changed value. So far  I tried the following.

```html
<button type='button' id="add">click</button>

<div id='cloneDoc'></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").change(function(event) {
      console.log(event.target);
    });
  });

  document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var htmlClone = '<input  type="number" name="a" value="50" /><br><input  type="number" name="b" value="46" /><br><br>'
    document.getElementById('cloneDoc').innerHTML += htmlClone;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Use event delegation `$(document).on('change','#cloneDoc input',function(event) {
      console.log($(this).val());
    });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the *value* attribute using jQuery's [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/). Also, I am not sure why you are mixing jQuery and JavaScript unnecessarily.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table").change(function(event) {
    $(event.target).attr('value', event.target.value);
    console.log(event.target);
  });
})


$("#add").on("click", function() {
  var htmlClone = '<input  type="number" name="a" value="50" /><br><input  type="number" name="b" value="46" /><br><br>';
  $('#cloneDoc').append(htmlClone);
});
```

```html
<button type='button' id="add">click</button>

<table id='cloneDoc'></table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I am a beginner of javascript and jquery. So I messed up these things. Highly appreciate for your help. But one thing I don't understand why the question become duplicated. I don't get my answer from the links.

Comment: @tuhin47, the question is not a duplicate at least for the given link. I really don't why it has been duplicated, may be that is done mistakenly:)

Answer (score 1):

```js
let obj = {a: 50, b: 46};
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table").change(function(event) {
    obj[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    $(event.target).attr("value", event.target.value);
  });
});

$("#add").click(function() {
  let htmlClone = `<input  type="number" name="a" value="${obj.a}" /><br><input  type="number" name="b" value="${obj.b}" /><br><br>`;
  debugger;
  document.getElementById('cloneDoc').innerHTML += htmlClone;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type='button' id="add">click</button>

<table id='cloneDoc'></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the HTML to `Div` element. Rather than you have to create the `input element` first and than try to apply the change event on it.